# Cite Author and Number (Index)

Tags: bibliographies, citing

How I can cite: `Author [Number]`?. For example:

> Wolsey [8]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Looking at what you are trying to accomplish, this is done by default in LaTeX when using `\cite` command. I think you will benefit from reading [`lshort`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort).

Comment: Also, we don't usually put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about). Once again, welcome, and enjoy learning with us in this community!

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this using the `natbib` package in numerical mode, and its `\citet` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % Hyperlinks bib references.
\begin{document}

  Here is a reference: \citet{Ca04}.
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 0):

I can do it using `flexbib` package and `\cite` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[plain*,spanish]{flexbib} %in this case the document is in spanish
\begin{document}

Here is a reference: \cite{Ca04}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and a numeric citation style you can use `\textcite`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code showing a citation Aksin et al. 1 and associated bibliography]

Answer (score -1):

```
\newcommand\Myciteauthor[1]{\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}
```

and use `\Myciteauthor` instead of `\citeauthor` in your text

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Without a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), your answer is unusable and can even be wrong because the output of cite will depend on the bibliography style used and might not provide a numbered citation.

Comment: The author never asked for the IEEE style as far as I can read, hence my comment. Moreover, I don't know who downvoted your answer.