# How to use multiple citation styles in the main document with elsarticle?

Tags: citing, elsarticle

I am trying to add author's name in addition to reference number with elsarticle. However with MWE given below I am unable to do so.

Expected output

[image]

MWE output

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[review, sort&compress, 12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\citeauthor{bailey1997quest} \cite{bailey1997quest}
\pagebreak
\section*{References}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

***How to get citation style in this format with elsarticle? I also need the references to be listed in the order they are cited in the main text***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `elsarticle-num-names` bibliography style instead of `elsarticle-num`. Moreover, to generate a citation call-out of the form "`Bailey et al [num]`", where the number "`num`" is a hyperlink, you should use `\citet`, not `\citeauthor` or `\cite`.

A full MWE -- observe how the outputs of `\citet`, `\citeauthor`, and `\cite` differ:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@misc{bailey1997quest,
  author = "Bailey, John and Daily, Gail and Malley, Micah",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 1997,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[review,12pt,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\citet{bailey1997quest}

\citeauthor{bailey1997quest}

\cite{bailey1997quest}

\section*{References}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `elsarticle-num-names` you will most probably run into another problem. See the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258758/bibliography-style-elsarticle-num-names-with-doi-and-hyperlinks-but-no-explicit

Comment: @TimKuipers - I'm not sure how the present posting (and my answer) might be related to the linked posting -- other than that both postings employ the `elsarticle-num-names` bibliography style. In particular, the present posting features neither a `doi` nor a `url` field -- how to display the `doi` field while not displaying the `url` field was the main concern of the linked posting.

Comment: chances are you have a doi field at some place in your bib already. Just add a doi field to the .bib of your MWE and you will get an error. The solution is the same as the solution to the post I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

a similar question was asked here:

[Cite Author and Number (Index)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103192/cite-author-and-number-index)

basically you can use the `natbib` package and `\citet`

Comment: But that changes the citation style, I want the references to be numbered in the order they appear in the main text like 'unsrt' style. 'plainnat' lists it alphabetically.

Comment: you mean you want  `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` ?